How can I get an async function to end once a global variable updates to a certain value?
So I'm trying to make a piece of code that watches my Twitch channel's channel point reward redeems and when a certain reward redeem occurs, it takes in the username of who redeemed the reward and then prints that users messages until it is stopped. I've got all the pieces working, but I'm having trouble getting the run_points_redeem_watcher() function to end once the global variable matches the one I'm looking for. I've got it working if I end it with an input, but for this to work how I need it to, I need it to effectively do what it does when I enter the input() command but instead of giving a command, it just sees that the global redeemName value has been changed to match the value I've told it to look for.
from twitchAPI.pubsub import PubSub
from twitchAPI.twitch import Twitch
from twitchAPI.helper import first
from twitchAPI.type import AuthScope, ChatEvent
from twitchAPI.chat import Chat, EventData, ChatMessage
from twitchAPI.oauth import UserAuthenticator
import asyncio
from uuid import UUID

APP_ID = 'App_Id_value'
APP_SECRET = 'App_Secret_value'
USER_SCOPE = [AuthScope.CHANNEL_READ_REDEMPTIONS, AuthScope.CHAT_READ]
TARGET_CHANNEL = 'channel_name_value'
redeemName = ""
redeemerName = ""

async def on_ready(ready_event: EventData):
    print('Bot is ready for work, joining channels')
    await ready_event.chat.join_room(TARGET_CHANNEL)

async def on_message(msg):
    if redeemerName.lower() == msg.user.name:
        print("the selected user said " + msg.text)

async def callback_points(uuid: UUID, data: dict):
    print('got callback for UUID ' + str(uuid))
    print(data["data"]["redemption"]["reward"]["title"])
    global redeemName
    redeemName = data["data"]["redemption"]["reward"]["title"]
    global redeemerName
    redeemerName = data["data"]["redemption"]["user"]["display_name"]


async def run_points_redeem_watcher():
    # setting up Authentication and getting your user id
    twitch = await Twitch(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
    auth = UserAuthenticator(twitch, USER_SCOPE, force_verify=False)
    token, refresh_token = await auth.authenticate()
    print("auth success")
    await twitch.set_user_authentication(token, USER_SCOPE, refresh_token)
    user = await first(twitch.get_users(logins=[TARGET_CHANNEL]))

    # starting up PubSub
    pubsub = PubSub(twitch)
    pubsub.start()
    uuid = await pubsub.listen_channel_points(user.id, callback_points)

    #The current code looks like this
    input('press ENTER to close...')
    pubsub.stop()
    await twitch.close()
    
    #What I would want to have work is something like this in theory
    if redeemName == "Correct Redeem Name Value":
        pubsub.stop()
        await twitch.close()

async def run_user_focused_chat():
    twitch = await Twitch(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
    auth = UserAuthenticator(twitch, USER_SCOPE, force_verify=False)
    token, refresh_token = await auth.authenticate()
    print("auth success")
    print("redeemer name is " + redeemerName)

    await twitch.set_user_authentication(token, USER_SCOPE, refresh_token)
    user = await first(twitch.get_users(logins=[TARGET_CHANNEL]))

    chat = await Chat(twitch)
    chat.register_event(ChatEvent.READY, on_ready)
    chat.start()
    chat.register_event(ChatEvent.MESSAGE, on_message)
    input('press ENTER to close...')
    chat.stop()
    await twitch.close()

asyncio.run(run_points_redeem_watcher())
if redeemName == "Correct Redeem Name Value":
    asyncio.run(run_user_focused_chat())

I've tried a few different ways to get the callback_points function to end after a certain value is achieved. But things like atexit and .exit()/.cancel()/.stop() either don't work, or they end the main run_points_redeem_watcher function but without properly closing out the pubsub and twitch functions, or just end the program on the whole, which isn't the goal.

Does this answer your question? Python Asyncio - Pythonic way of waiting until condition satisfied

You can use an asynchio.Event() as demonstrated here. Current Python Documentation describes it here.  Create the Event instance in the main loop.  When the name gets set to the target name, call flag.set().  Then after the trigger occurs and you aren't in state that will immediately reset based on the last input, call flag.clear(). I would recommend passing the Event object around instead of making it global.

I tried to implement the Event and flag technique, but the issue is that I can't pass the flag into the callback_points function. When I try to it gives me the error: "ValueError: callback_func needs to be a async function which takes 2 arguments"
the twitchAPI library is pretty restrictive as the function only takes in the UUID and Dict values and returns the UUID. I can get the values from inside the data: Dict within the callback_points function, but without mapping them to global variables I can't get them out of the function, or pass any new values in.

Are you able to add the event instance to the Dict object being passed in?  If not, a global instance of the Event should work.  I haven't worked with the Twitch APIs at all myself, so I can't give direct answers on that.

I do appreciate the help. I did try using the flag as a global and was able to get it to call the set() method. Or at least it triggered the print() I had after the flag.set(). But even with the set() triggered, it would never trigger the "await flag.wait()", or again not the print() that followed it.  I think it might be because there are two awaits running and even with the "await flag.wait()" met, the "await pubsub.listen_channel_points()" was still running. I think I need some way to kill that await.
